# C# .mdf connection failed

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am facing the following problem in my VS 2013

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Here is the code:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source =.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security = True; User Instance = True;");
myConnection.Open();

SqlCommand  myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customer";

SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

myConnection.Close();

foreach(DataRow myRow in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myRow["FirstName"]+" " +myRow["LastName"]);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Try catching the exception and logging the message within it...

Comment: try by removing user instance = true

Comment: check the .mdf file specified is there in APP folder..also like Buddy's comment put the connection inside a try..catch statement and get the exact error..then its easy to fix

Comment: The type of the exception indicates that it has something to do with SQL, but like Buddy said, the actual exception MESSAGE is what indicates what the actual exception was.

Comment: Exception:Caught: "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Saeef\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ADO2DisConnected\ADO2DisConnected\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.